# In Java, how can I avoid blank jtextfield input?

Tags: java, null, jtextfield

Due to a gui with a lot of buttons and labels, I'm using netbeans.  When I test-run it in netbeans, if I leave the jtextfield blank and submit it, I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

I was looking at the jbutton I am using to submit the data and although I can see the following field, I cannot edit it:

```
        butSub.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            butSubActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

I thought maybe in that I could run an if or a try/catch block, but again it won't let me edit it. If the user inputs nothing, I want it to tell them so and then return to the start.

Comment: if ( text.getText().isEmpty()){ doNothing(); } else{ process(text.getText()); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to edit IDE generated code. Don't do that. Instead edit the code in `butSubActionPerformed()` which is being called by the `ActionListener`. You can check if the text field is empty using:

```
if(jTextField.getText().isEmpty()){
    //error
} else //every thing is fine, you can continue.
```

Again, this code has to be in the method being called by the ActionListener.

Comment: @user3377627 I'm glad I was able to help.